# 'Stiffening' capacitor/s for DIY flash battery pack?

Tags: capacitor, charging

I'm planning to build a [DIY battery pack](http://joeharper.net/2010/12/07/battery-pack-fo-vivitar-285hv/) for one of my camera flashes that involves basically [wiring a bigger external battery](http://www.comatosed.ca/writing/writing/reviews/DIY_Vivitar_285_HV_Battery_Pack.html) to the battery leads in the flash. Admittedly I don't know much about electronics but keep my feet just oh-so wet in it.

The main goal for doing this is actually to improve recycle times of the flash with the added benefit of longevity from the battery.

Question #1 is: Whether or not there would be any benefit to adding a capacitor or two to provide a limited rapid-charge for a quicker, subsequent re-charge after the flash goes off the first time.

My rationale is: often the flow of taking photos involves a flash or two; or three; change spots/framing/talk to subject (which by then the capacitor/s might be recharged to supply the benefit again)

Question #2 is: Is there a formal word/phrase for what this process (a capacitor used for rapid discharge in tandem with a battery) is so I can do further research for academic purposes.

More details:
The battery supply is 6V - there's a variance on how much the flash is willing to draw based on the supply (4AA's vs. the bigger battery mentioned in my links); I don't know what, or if there are limitations on what kind of current the flash can draw (hence if it can benefit from caps). There's an external AC adapter that supplies 200V@4mA for the flash.

Comment: From my limited experience with looking into faster recycle times, I've read much about higher voltages helping.  This was mostly on the form on NiZn AA batteries that have a nominal cell voltage of 1.65V vs an alkaline's 1.5V, or worse yet, a 1.2V NiMH.  I'd investigate if anyone has done any work with these batteries for your flash and experienced faster recycle times.  You might be able to extrapolate that work into your battery pack, providing the increased voltage and increased longevity all in one fell swoop.. although an external pack is gonna help no matter what. :)

Comment: @TobyLawrence I've absolutely considered doing a modest voltage jump based off what you've mentioned; the circuitry for a step up is a bit more complicated than I'd feel comfortable with; and the SLA batteries are cheaper in comparison to the NiZn AA's in a similar capacity; tough decision

Comment: Also FWIW - the tests I've seen with NiZn batteries vs NiMH was that they had better performance until about half-charge, which at that point they fall behind the NiMH; so they really were quite close but didn't hold a card to the external pack

Comment: Right, but what I was mostly getting at was using this DIY project to exploit the best of both worlds - higher pack voltage and higher pack capacity. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there would be much benefit to adding a capacitor across your battery. Consider the following:

- The charging of the flash can be seen as a process of moving energy from the battery to the high-voltage capacitor in the flash.
- Based on some quick searches, the capacitor in the Vivitar 285HV is 1000 uF. Assuming it's charged to 200V, it stores 20 J of energy
- A capacitor to hold 20 J at 6V would be 1.1 Farads, and that's just enough energy for a single charge of the HV cap. Assuming 50% conversion efficiency, and that we want 3 shots that's a 6 F capacitor. The least expensive capacitor I found with some margin over the 6 V working voltage and with that kind of capacitance was over $100, and 8 inches long.
- Just to supply 20 J directly from a 6V battery in 1 second with 50% efficiency would mean a current draw of about 6.7 A. That's a lot of current, but it's something that a large battery can do.
- The charging circuit in the flash will limit how quickly we can charge no matter how much power is available at the input. An easy way to see if the charging circuit is the limiting factor rather than the input power is to measure the voltage across the battery while the flash is charging. If the voltage remains close to the open circuit voltage of the battery, then it's the charging circuit that's limiting, not the battery.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your thoroughness. I guess what I was looking for wasn't to store the energy for a second or third flash; but rather to hasten the recharge after the first flash. So ideally something like: [full charge][flash][1.5sec][flash][4sec][flash] if that makes sense. Sadly, I tried looking for the capacitor's farads and couldn't find it; good searches!

Comment: For those interested, in the case of the battery and flash this question regards, the battery voltage dips quite good when under full draw.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using a professional-grade flash, it has a pretty big capacitor inside it already (at high voltage, so don't mess with it).  Your flash has what's called a DC-to-DC converter inside it that takes battery voltage in, increases the voltage substantially (usually to several hundred volts), then uses it to charge a very large capacitor internal to the flash.  When the flash fires, the capacitor partially or fully discharges into the flash tube.  Most flash heads allow several flashes before a recharge interval is required; it's this internal capacitor that makes that possible.

The classic flash recharge "whine" is the sound of this DC/DC converter working - older units ran at an audible frequency that increased as the capacitor reached full charge.  Newer flash units have a switching frequency above the audible range, so the whine can't be heard in most cases.

If your goal is reduced cycle times on your flash, a good quality external battery and decent sized wire between the external battery and the flash may be all that is required.  Batteries have something called parasitic series resistance, which is undesirable and causes the voltage at the terminals to droop as more current is pulled from the battery.  This limits the peak power that can be pulled from a battery, which is likely a limiting factor in your flash's cycle times using internal batteries.

Usually, a larger capacity battery will have a lower parasitic series resistance, and therefore can supply higher peak power.  This changes with battery chemistry, state of charge, temperature, etc., but for your application a larger battery pack, with a likely lower series resistance, will likely improve your recharge times even without an additional external (low voltage) capacitor.  I'd suggest that you try it just with a larger battery and see if it meets your expectations.

Comment: The flash is professional grade, and has the 'whine' from the converter. I'm already sure it will meet expectations, I'm just looking for outside the box approaches to be able to 'dump' energy into the flash at a faster rate than the battery. (as I understand it, the key difference between cap and battery is the trade off in capacity for responsiveness)

Comment: The difference between cap and battery is specific energy storage (energy per unit weight or per unit volume) vs. peak power.  Capacitors have a lower series resistance, so can supply (or sink) higher peak power, but don't store much energy.  The problem with things that can source a lot of energy is that they require safe handling.  Most folks don't worry about shorting an AA battery for a moment, but you'd never try that with a car battery.  While you might marginally improve your cycle times by adding a large capacitor near the flash head, you'd need to consider safety to do it, um, safely.

Comment: Assuming proper wiring gauge & contact surfaces; you're saying a cap(or caps) located ~5-6' down from the flash head would be a wash because of resistance?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying that if you are looking for out of the box solutions and peak performance, the benefit of the cap is maximized if mounted as close to the flash unit as possible to minimize the impact of wiring and contact resistance.  You'll still want to consider current limiting and reverse polarity protection at the capacitor to prevent melted/welded conductors, exploding caps, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input; I would ensure current protection as you suggest. Would it be safe to assume the answer to my #2 question is just an example of "power supply smoothing"?

Comment: I've usually called such a device a bulk capacitor, but you could also call it a peak buffer, pulse supply, or spot welder ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a SuperCap which are intermediate between Caps and Batteries for energy density.  It's not recommended that you plug in a uncharged supercap to a battery because of the high current flow.  But this will certainly smooth out the voltage droop from high current draw.